# Unity PlayerPrefs is returning the deafult value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My code is:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Denemeint",2);
PlayerPrefs.Save();
print(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Denemeint"));
```

When i start my game, it writes 2 on my screen. It is okay.
But when i close my game and rewrite this code:

```
print(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Denemeint"));
```

And after play game, it gives me 0 on my screen. What is my code's problem? I want to save my simple variables but I can't save anything in this situation. Please help me.

Comment: Is this happening in the Editor or a build? It would be good to mention the Platform and the Unity version. Also, are you sure this is not a typo problem?

Comment: My Unity version is : 5.6.1f1. I using VisualStudio 2017. It's version is 15.2. There is no syntax error in Unity. When game open, it works. But when i close game and after hit play button, it is not get my variables value.

Comment: Ok. 1.Does this happen in the Editor or build? 2.What is your platform? When I said typo, I meant misspelling `Denemeint` in either `SetInt` or `GetInt` function.

Comment: int x=2;
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("try",x);
    print(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("try"));
When i hit play button in unity, it gives me 2.When i stop my game and when i organize my code like this:
    //int x=2;
    //PlayerPrefs.SetInt("try",x);
    print(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("try"));
    //PlayerPrefs.Save();
it gives me 0 again.
And my platform is Windows 8.1

Comment: I opened a new project and it works. It is interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the value you are trying to retrieve to a variable first.

```
int myPrefsValue = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("MyInt");
Debug.Log(myPrefsValue);
```

If you really want to ensure your values are being saved correctly, take a look at this asset. I highly recommend it and I use it myself.

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/26656

Comment: Link is 404, but unity still offers a [backup link](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/playersprefs-editor-and-utilities-26656). Asset is free and called "PlayersPrefs Editor and Utilities".